# Prove that $\ f(x)=2x^2 -x$ is convex

Tags: calculus

I know that$\ f$ is convex if

$\ λf(x)+(1-λ)f(y) \ge f(λx +(1-λ)y)$, that is:

$\ λ(2x^2 -x)+(1-λ)(2y^2 -y) \ge 2(λx +(1-λ)y)^2 - (λx +(1-λ)y)$

The last inequality is equivalent to:

$\ 0 \ge (1-λ)(2λxy)+(1-λ)^2 (y^2) +2(λ^2 - λ)(x^2)-(1-λ)(2y^2 -y)$

I'm stuck at this at this point, how can I go on with the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that the second derivative is positive everywhere.
$$
f(x) = 2x^2 - x\\
f'(x) = 4x - 1\\
f''(x) = 4
$$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to prove it via the definition I was given

Comment: @DavidTomahak Then you should have mentioned it :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The sum of two convex functions is convex.

Comment: So if I take $\ f(x)=2x^2$ and $\ g(x)=-x$, I've already proved that $\ f(x)=2x^2$ is convex, but what about $\ g(x)=-x$? is it convex? isn't it just a line?

Comment: @DavidTomahak Yes. And that's convex (not strictly however).

Comment: A linear function is both convex  and concave.

Answer (score 1):

Show that $f$ is midpoint convex that is $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=2\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2-x-y}{2}\leq \frac{2x^2-x+2y^2-y}{2}=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$
Last inequality comes from $x^2+y^2\geq 2xy\iff(x-y)^2\geq0.$ And use that a continuous function that is midpoint convex is convex.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=2x^2-x \ $
$f'(x)=4x-1 \ $
$f''(x)=4 >0 \ => f\ is\ convex$